# PyQt Different colors in a single row in a combobox

Tags: colors, pyqt, rtf, qcombobox

I'm developing a UI using PyQt where a single item in my Qcombobox can have two or three words separated by commas. So for eg item 1 can be '*Text1, Text2, Text3*' and item 2 will be '*Text4, Text5*'.

What I want to do is give multiple background colors to the items separated by the ',' in the itemText. So, in case of item 1 ('*Text1, Text2, Text3*') I would need a color behind *Text1*, a different one behind *Text2* and a third one behind *Text3*. Similarly, item 2 would have 2 background colors.

I was thinking of using rtf format, but could not figure out a way to give multiple colors to one item row.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: To change the background color of the words in the same text, I think you should use html tags. But since the comboBox won't interpret the tags, you have to create a delegate to display your text. This delegate will be in charge of interpreting the html tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a [QTextDocument](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html) to render rich-text for combobox items (via a custom [delegate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html)), and also to convert the rich-text back to plain-text for the current text of the combo-box (via its [paint event](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#paintEvent)).

This would allow you to use html for the item text, like so:

```python
    self.combo = RichTextCombo(self)
    self.combo.addItem("""
        <span style="background-color: blue">Blue</span>
        <span style="background-color: red">Red</span>
        """)
```

Here's the combobox class:

```python
class RichTextCombo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RichTextCombo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._document = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)
        self._delegate = RichTextDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(self._delegate)
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
            QtGui.QComboBox.AdjustToMinimumContentsLength)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Text))
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(options)
        self._document.setHtml(options.currentText)
        options.currentText = self._document.toPlainText()
        painter.drawComplexControl(QtGui.QStyle.CC_ComboBox, options)
        painter.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, options)
```

and here's the custom item-delegate:

```python
class RichTextDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RichTextDelegate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._document = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        if options.widget is not None:
            style = options.widget.style()
        else:
            style = QtGui.QApplication.style()
        self._document.setHtml(options.text)
        options.text = ''
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)
        context = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if options.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:
            context.palette.setColor(
                QtGui.QPalette.Text, options.palette.color(
                    QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText))
        textRect = style.subElementRect(
            QtGui.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)
        painter.save()
        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self._document.documentLayout().draw(painter, context)
        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options,index)
        self._document.setHtml(options.text)
        self._document.setTextWidth(options.rect.width())
        return QtCore.QSize(self._document.idealWidth(),
                            self._document.size().height())
```